# Question about Silent-Installation with Inno Setup 5.6.1

Tags: installation, silent

I'm new in this business - so at first, sorry for my very bad English. I hope you will understand my question. I´m working as Admin in a small company, we have a software-deployment and for doing our software-packages we ware using PowerShellAppDeployToolkit.

The most packages I do, are working good. But now I have a software... grrrr

The Software is using an Inno Setup Installer Version 5.6.1. I perform the installation "install.exe /VERYSILENT" and it works fine, with a small problem. Before the main-installation begins, there is a Dialog-Box asking to search for available updates... how to disable this dialog-box... skip or say no, I don't mind. But I really not find the parameter I need to use for this.... how to find out.

I hope you know, what I'm Searching for.... and sorry again for bad English. I hope, this is the right place to ask my question.

I already tried some parameters (/SP-...) I thought... but no one helped...

install.exe /? don't give me information for this Dialog....

Comment: OMG I fount something... https://unattended.sourceforge.net/InnoSetup_Switches_ExitCodes.html

/SUPPRESSMSGBOXES
Instructs Setup to suppress message boxes. Only has an effect when combined with '/SILENT' and '/VERYSILENT'.
5 message boxes are not suppressible:
arameters.

Any (error) message box displayed before Setup (or Uninstall) could read the command line p
Any message box displayed by [Code] support function MsgBox.

Does this mean, I can´t skip the message box displayed before the installation?!